# Database design - double up of data in columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

From a database design perspective, which of the following would be considered best practice?:

If you need to store a category and a subcategory for a record of data (both integers), the options I can see are:

a) Store the category and subcategory in separate fields (difficult to see what category a particular subcategory has at a glance)

b) Store both in the same field separated by a period (data summaries or category level analysis would require a function to be run over each record to extract the Category)

c) Store the Category and Subcategory separately, but combine them in the Subcategory field (i.e. Category = 1, Subcategory = 1.2) (The Category data would be doubled up, and there exists a chance that the Subcategory would be incongruous with the Category)

Or is there another approach that would be considered better practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on how 'category' and 'subcategory' are going to be used, what those represent.

One question we need to ask is whether 'category' is functionally dependent on 'subcategory'.

That is: does a 'subcategory' "belong" to a single 'category', or is a 'subcategory' generalized, in that it applies to multiple categories?

In the latter case, then storing 'category' and 'subcategory' as two separate columns is the normative pattern.

In the first case, where 'category' is functionally dependent on 'subcategory', We could just store 'subcategory', and avoid storing 'category' in the "record". We could store the relationship between 'category' and 'subcategory' in a separate table, normalizing the model.

We could still opt to denormalize the model, and go ahead and redundantly store the 'category' column for performance reasons. We just have to recognize the redundancy, and take measures to ensure consistency: to make sure that the 'category' stored in the "record" matches the 'category' that is associated with the 'subcategory' stored in the "record".

---

There may be some good reasons for a different representation, to store the values of 'category' and 'subcategory' a different way. But absent any idea of how those values will be used, without some description of the uses cases, we can't make that recommendation.

Comment: "to make sure that the 'category' stored in the "record" matches the 'category' that is associated with the 'subcategory'" - Define a FK `records(category, subcategory)` referencing `subcategeries(category, subcategory)` and let the RDBMS check the consistency. The same should also work with a many-to-many table.

Comment: I think in a generalized approach this is a spot on answer.  I think the only additional consideration would be if categories and sub-categories have some sort of Ragged Hierarchy, in which case the modeling of that scenario looks different.

Comment: @BradD: Yes, excellent point. Data analysis and entity relationship modeling are the keys to relational database design. From the rather general question that was posed, we don't really know what "record of data", "category" and "subcategory" *really* represent. Those are just labels. And we take caution not to burden those labels with inferred semantic rules, just from suggestions of possible representations. A more thorough analysis would lead us to discover the actual requirements, and based on that, we can make decisions on representation.

Comment: @spencer7593 You're right - I didn't specify the relationship between category and subcategory in the question. I should have specified that the subcategories are functionally related to the categories - each subcategory has a single related category, basically just a higher level of detail.

Answer (score 2):

The first option is the best practice. Do some research on something called "normalization". I like [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-LQRiRbSSA). For the DB to be in first normal form, data needs to be atomic.

Answer (score 2):

You already laid down the pros and cons of a-c.

IF you do not simply allow *any and all* combinations of cat and sub-cat,
I'd rather do the following:

Have a table `categories` and a table `sub-categories`.
Then have a table `cat_subcat` that brings them together - but only the valid combinations. `cat_subcat` has it's own id's. These you use as a the only reference when you reference them.

I personally do prefer a special sub-category `none` over any usage of null's or other special handling.